# function works perfectly fine outside ddply but throws an error inside ddply

Tags: r, plyr

I am trying to do row-wise operation (by group) on a data frame. When I run the function by itself for just one group, it runs perfectly fine. However, when I put the function inside ddply to run it for all the groups, it throws an error - argument is of length zero.

The function when run separately on a data frame 'test':

```
for (i in 1:(nrow(test) - 5)) {

  if (i <= 5) {
    test[i, "MPPALERT"] <- 0    
  }

  FIRSTMPP <- test[i, "TAGMPPSEARCHCOUNT"]
  LASTMPP <- test[i+5, "TAGMPPSEARCHCOUNT"]

  if ((LASTMPP - FIRSTMPP) >= 10) {
    test[i+5, "MPPALERT"] <- 1    
  } else {
    test[i+5, "MPPALERT"] <- 0    
  }

}
```

The above function inside ddply throws the error:

```
Error in if (LASTMPP - FIRSTMPP >= 10) { : argument is of length zero
```

Below is the ddply code:

```
mpp_fn <- function(x) {  

  for (i in 1:(nrow(x) - 5)) {

    if (i <= 5) {
      x[i, "MPPALERT"] <- 0    
    }

    FIRSTMPP <- x[i, "TAGMPPSEARCHCOUNT"]
    LASTMPP <- x[i+5, "TAGMPPSEARCHCOUNT"]

    if (LASTMPP - FIRSTMPP >= 10) {
      x[i+5, "MPPALERT"] <- 1    
    } else {
      x[i+5, "MPPALERT"] <- 0    
    }

  }

}

result <- ddply(data, c("SHELTERID", "INVERTERID"), mpp_fn(x))
```

In the above code, the values of FIRSTMPP and LASTMPP are resolving to NULL and therefore the error, but why is this happening (when it runs perfectly fine outside ddply)?

UPDATE: Here is the output of dput(data):

```
structure(list(SHELTERID = c("SH02", "SH02", "SH02", "SH02", 
"SH02", "SH02", "SH02", "SH02", "SH02", "SH02", "SH02", "SH02", 
"SH02", "SH02", "SH02", "SH02", "SH02", "SH02", "SH02", "SH02", 
"SH02", "SH02", "SH02", "SH02", "SH02", "SH02", "SH02", "SH02", 
"SH02", "SH02", "SH02", "SH02", "SH02", "SH02", "SH02", "SH02", 
"SH03", "SH03", "SH03", "SH03", "SH03", "SH03", "SH03", "SH03", 
"SH03", "SH03", "SH03", "SH03", "SH03", "SH03", "SH03", "SH03", 
"SH03", "SH03", "SH03", "SH03", "SH03", "SH03", "SH03", "SH03", 
"SH03", "SH03", "SH03", "SH03", "SH03", "SH03", "SH03", "SH03", 
"SH03", "SH03", "SH03", "SH03"), INVERTERID = c("I1", "I1", "I1", 
"I1", "I1", "I1", "I1", "I1", "I1", "I1", "I1", "I1", "I1", "I1", 
"I1", "I1", "I1", "I1", "I2", "I2", "I2", "I2", "I2", "I2", "I2", 
"I2", "I2", "I2", "I2", "I2", "I2", "I2", "I2", "I2", "I2", "I2", 
"I1", "I1", "I1", "I1", "I1", "I1", "I1", "I1", "I1", "I1", "I1", 
"I1", "I1", "I1", "I1", "I1", "I1", "I1", "I2", "I2", "I2", "I2", 
"I2", "I2", "I2", "I2", "I2", "I2", "I2", "I2", "I2", "I2", "I2", 
"I2", "I2", "I2"), TAGMPPSEARCHCOUNT = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 4, 0, 4, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 
5, 0)), .Names = c("SHELTERID", "INVERTERID", "TAGMPPSEARCHCOUNT"
), row.names = c(350L, 351L, 352L, 353L, 354L, 355L, 356L, 357L, 
358L, 359L, 360L, 361L, 362L, 363L, 364L, 365L, 366L, 367L, 494L, 
495L, 496L, 497L, 498L, 499L, 500L, 501L, 502L, 503L, 504L, 505L, 
506L, 507L, 508L, 509L, 510L, 511L, 638L, 639L, 640L, 641L, 642L, 
643L, 644L, 645L, 646L, 647L, 648L, 649L, 650L, 651L, 652L, 653L, 
654L, 655L, 782L, 783L, 784L, 785L, 786L, 787L, 788L, 789L, 790L, 
791L, 792L, 793L, 794L, 795L, 796L, 797L, 798L, 799L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: can provide a reproducible example by posting the output of `dput(data)`. Please don't use the complete `data` but only a minimal subset of it

Comment: Sure @Thierry. Below is a small subset of the data.

Comment: please add the output of `dput(data)` not just `data`. the output of `dput(data)` makes is very easy to copy paste your data into our R session.

Comment: Thanks @Thierry. I have just added the output of dput(data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a `dplyr` solution. It doesn't require the explicit loops

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  group_by(SHELTERID, INVERTERID) %>% 
  mutate(
    First = lag(TAGMPPSEARCHCOUNT, 5), 
    MPPALERT = ifelse(
      is.na(First),
      0,
      ifelse(
        TAGMPPSEARCHCOUNT - First > 10, 
        1, 
        0
      )
    )
  )
```